# Merge two csv files with custom columns

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two csv files:
test1

```
A   B 
1   a
2   b
3   c
4   d
5   e
```

test2

```
A   C   D   B
3   x   25  101
2   y   0.35    11
1   z   0.45    111
6   k   0.55    1101
7   l   0.65    1010
```

I want to merge them on = A but i need only the columns test1.A,B and test2.D, B in the final file. And since both these files have a same column name B, need to rename it while joining itself. The output file should be like this:

```
A   B   D       B1
1   a   0.45    1110
2   b   0.35    1010
3   c   25      1011
4   d       
5   e   0.55    
6       0.65    1000
7               1111
```

where B1 corresponds to column B in Table2. Both B columns in test1 and test2 are not same.

```
import pandas

csv1 = pandas.read_csv('test1.csv',dtype='unicode')
csv2 = pandas.read_csv('test2.csv',dtype='unicode')
merged = pandas.merge(csv1[list('AB')],csv2[list('DB')], on='A',how="outer")
merged.to_csv("outputtest.csv", index=False)
```

This is giving me error:

> KeyError: "['B'] not in index"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) column `C` in `csv2` and then [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with parameter `suffixes` and last [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) by empty `string`:

```
merged = pd.merge(csv1,
                  csv2.drop('C', axis=1), 
                  on='A',
                  how="outer", 
                  suffixes=('','1')).fillna('')
print (merged)
     A  B     D    B1
0  1.0  a  0.45   111
1  2.0  b  0.35    11
2  3.0  c    25   101
3  4.0  d            
4  5.0  e            
5  6.0     0.55  1101
6  7.0     0.65  1010
```

If in `csv` is many columns, you can use subset - only columns which need and column for join - in this solution column `A`:

```
merged = pd.merge(csv1[['A','B']],
                  csv2[['A','D','B']], 
                  on='A',
                  how="outer", 
                  suffixes=('','1')).fillna('')
print (merged)
     A  B     D    B1
0  1.0  a  0.45   111
1  2.0  b  0.35    11
2  3.0  c    25   101
3  4.0  d            
4  5.0  e            
5  6.0     0.55  1101
6  7.0     0.65  1010
```

Or:

```
merged = pd.merge(csv1[list('AB')],
                  csv2[list('ADB')], 
                  on='A',
                  how="outer", 
                  suffixes=('','1')).fillna('')
print (merged)
     A  B     D    B1
0  1.0  a  0.45   111
1  2.0  b  0.35    11
2  3.0  c    25   101
3  4.0  d            
4  5.0  e            
5  6.0     0.55  1101
6  7.0     0.65  1010
```

Comment: I think this error means you have maybe some space in column names - try check it by `print csv1.columns`.

Comment: Instead of suffix, if we need to rename the column name altogether say make it 'BiNumeral' instead of B, what would be the approach. Should i change the names while reading csv2 or is there a shorter way?

Comment: IIUC you can use `df.rename(columns={'B':'BiNumeral'}, inplace=True)
`

Comment: yup. I did something like that. `import pandas

csv1 = pandas.read_csv('test1.csv',dtype='unicode')
csv2 = pandas.read_csv('test2.csv',dtype='unicode')
csv2 = csv2.rename(columns={'C':'Binomial'})
merged = pandas.merge(csv1,csv2[['A','Binomial','D']], on='A')
merged.to_csv("outputtest.csv", index=False)`

Comment: One last doubt, if i need the output to give only the rows of test1, which join do i need to perform. If i do an inner join it gives only the rows which have same id., i.e it gives me rows where A=1,2,3 but i want rows with A=1,2,3,4,5

Comment: I think you need parameter `how='left'` instead `how='inner'`